# Can't pass string to the next activity

Tags: java, android, xml, database, firebase

1st activity

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsers model) {
            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());


            final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);

                    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });


                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", user_id);
                    intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", name);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
```

2nd Activity

```
name.setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Name")));
MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id");
```

The id is getting passed but the name is not... im sure its the problem lies in fetching it from the database

Screenshot - https://ibb.co/mBKZLd

i can fetch the id from the database since its the parent... but i cant fetch its child which is "Name"... can someone point out where i have gone wrong

Comment: debug your app and mark 2 lines and check `user_id` and `name` is getting or not in 1st activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method is called asynchronously. You are putting `name` in `Intent` before getting its value. You have to start your `Activity` after you get name. Start your Chat `Activity` inside `onDataChange` method.

```
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);

                reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
                      intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", user_id);
                      intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", name);

                      startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method is called **asynchronously**. You are putting name in Intent before getting its value. You have to start your Activity after you get name. Start your Chat Activity inside onDataChange method.

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);

                reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
                      intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", user_id);
                      intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", name);

                      startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```